# How to covert this expression to LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

Hi I have this **FilterAlerts** Function which I think can be implemented using LINQ. I am fairly new to C# and need help converting it. Also is there a better way to assign errors to the expression in the end?

```
 new public BusinessProfileStateModel Create(BusinessProfileViewModel profileViewModel)
    {
        var businessProfileState = base.Create(profileViewModel);
        if (profileViewModel != null)
        {
            businessProfileState.DialogLocations = profileViewModel.DialogLocations;
            businessProfileState.IsCommunityMember = profileViewModel.IsCommunityMember;
            businessProfileState.IsLocalReport = profileViewModel.IsLocalReport;
            businessProfileState.IsMultiLocation = profileViewModel.IsMultiLocation;
        }
        return FilterAlerts(businessProfileState);
    }
    private BusinessProfileStateModel FilterAlerts(BusinessProfileStateModel businessProfileStateModel)
    {
        var errors = new List<BPAlert>();
        foreach (BPAlert alert in businessProfileStateModel.Display.Alerts.AllAlerts)
        {
            if (AlertFinderUtil.IsValidAlertTypeId(alert))
            {
                errors.Add(alert);
            }
        }
        businessProfileStateModel.Display.Alerts.AllAlerts = errors;
        return businessProfileStateModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably have the keyword ref inside your signature if you're passing by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
businessProfileStateModel.Display.Alerts.AllAlerts = 
businessProfileState.Display.Alerts.AllAlerts.Where(alert => AlertFinderUtil.IsValidAlertTypeId(alert)).ToList();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're missing the `AlertFinderUtil` and it can be just `Where(AlertFinderUtil.IsValidAlertTypeId)` since that method matches the delegate.

Comment: True, added to the anwser